# Bounty awarded to low score answer

Tags: support, bounty

I am confused about a bounty awarded to me. I answered a question and my score was 3 another answer had score of 4 but bounty was awarded to me even my answer was not accepted as correct answer. As per rules what i understand is bounty should be awarded to the answer with highest score. Here is a link to question [Populate Text boxes based on drop down list in 3 tier application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429855/populate-text-boxes-based-on-drop-down-list-in-3-tier-application/29738788#29738788)

Comment: If that's a rule I want to turn myself in because I just awarded a 500 points bounty to a -1 answer, skipping a +3 answer. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The person who started the bounty never came back to award it, so the system automatically awarded half of the bounty for them. When bounties are automatically awarded, only answers posted while the bounty was active are eligible to receive it. The answer with score of 4 was posted well before the bounty started, so your answer, also having a score of at least 2, was the only one that was eligible.